# Is there problem in instagram's "graphql" api? Volley library giving error when I make request

Tags: java, android-studio, graphql, android-volley, instagram-graph-api

I'm trying to get data from Instagram's graphql api.
I'm making request to "https://www.instagram.com/p/CQWYMTlqB9w/?__a=1" and volley giving me this error: `Something went wrong com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject`
It was working well until morning but when I used it before few hours then it started to give that error. for some users it is giving [this error](https://prnt.sc/16m3p24)

Is graphql having any issues or problem with volley?
( if we add `?__a=1` to the end of any post link then it gives post data in the json form)

```java
private void downloadInstaImage() {

        dialog.show();

        RequestQueue requestQueue;
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(InstaImages.this);

        if (binding.instImageaurl.getText().toString().contains("?utm_source=ig_web_copy_link")) {
            String partToRemove = "?utm_source=ig_web_copy_link";
            image = binding.instImageaurl.getText().toString().replace(partToRemove, "");
        } else if (binding.instImageaurl.getText().toString().contains("?utm_source=ig_web_button_share_sheet")) {
            String partToRemove = "?utm_source=ig_web_button_share_sheet";
            image = binding.instImageaurl.getText().toString().replace(partToRemove, "");
        } else {
            image = binding.instImageaurl.getText().toString();
        }



        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                image + "?__a=1", null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                JSONObject Obj1 = null;
                try {
                    Obj1 = response.getJSONObject("graphql");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                JSONObject Obj2 = null;
                try {
                    Obj2 = Obj1.getJSONObject("shortcode_media");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                String finalImageUrl = null;
                try {
                    finalImageUrl = Obj2.getString("display_url");

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Log.d("myapp", finalImageUrl);
                    Util.download(finalImageUrl, Util.RootDirectoryInstaImages, InstaImages.this, "insta" + ".png");
                    dialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Downloading Started...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }


        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                Log.e("myapp", "Something went wrong " + error);
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);

    }
```

Comment: This is not an issue with Volley, I tried the same thing using Retrofit. The get request is returning HTML instead JSON that's what the issue is

Comment: @SreehariK Thanks for the letting me know about it. How to convert that to JSON form?

Comment: Me too don't know its working on both browser and postman. I'll let you know if I get a solution

Comment: hm, I figured out that when I go to that link on private window or without instagram login it shows login page. Maybe because that, issue occured.

Comment: It works for me with private tabs